# VB.NET: can't read database records with MySQL Data Reader dr.HasRows

Tags: mysql, vb.net

when i click the button 2 with the valid ID No. on the text box it always shows the message box "Invalid ID No." but if i remove the `IF` statement, it shows database records and it works fine, but i need this `IF` statement, i think the problem here is the `dr.HasRows` but i don't know what to put.

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class Form16
    Private Sub Form16_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim con As New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;user id=root;password=root;database=db")
        Dim DataSet1 As New DataSet
        Dim dr As MySqlDataReader
        Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand

        con.ConnectionString = "server = localhost; user id = root;password=root; database = db"
        cmd.Connection = con
        con.Open()
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from voter where idn='" & TextBox1.Text & "'"
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        con.Close()
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        da.Fill(DataSet1, "db")


        If dr.HasRows Then
            Label2.DataBindings.Add("text", DataSet1, "db.fname")
            Label10.DataBindings.Add("text", DataSet1, "db.mi")
            Label11.DataBindings.Add("text", DataSet1, "db.lname")
            Label12.DataBindings.Add("text", DataSet1, "db.yr")
            Label13.DataBindings.Add("text", DataSet1, "db.sec")
            Label14.DataBindings.Add("text", DataSet1, "db.vstatus")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid ID No.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End If

        Label2.DataBindings.Clear()
        Label10.DataBindings.Clear()
        Label11.DataBindings.Clear()
        Label12.DataBindings.Clear()
        Label13.DataBindings.Clear()
        Label14.DataBindings.Clear()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: `select * from voter where idn='" & TextBox1.Text & "'` You are open for sql-injection. Use parameters. Apart from that, why do you use a datareader if you use a dataset anyway? You can access the table you fill in this way: `Dim db As DataTable = DataSet1.Tables("db")` and it's rows via `db.Rows`.

Comment: sorry i'm just a beginner in vb.net and i really don't how to do what you are saying. can you please explain more?

Comment: is idn a number? if so remove the quote so that you have... idn=" & TextBox1.Text   .... as Tim mentioned you should learn to use parameters.

Comment: yes it is a number, but still not working :( can someone please help me on this? please? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `Parameterized` query to prevent [SQL Injection](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)

```
Dim commandText as String = "SELECT * FROM Voter WHERE idn=@idn"
Dim command As New MySqlCommand(commandText, connection)

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idn", TextBox1.Text)
```

You don't need to use `DataSet` and `DataAdapter` if you are using a `DataReader` because you could convert your `DataReader` to a `DataTable`:

```
dr = command.ExecuteReader() ' Get Data Reader Rows
dt.Load(dr) 'Convert DataReader into DataTable
```

Which now could be bind to your `Label` or `TextBox`:

```
Label2.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt, "fname")
```

You don't need then to use `HasRows` property to check if `DataReader` has rows, instead you could check the `Row Count` of your `DataTable`:

```
If (dt.Rows.Count > 0) Then
    Label2.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt, "fname")
End If
```

I am also using the `Using` statement in dotNet specially for connection so that you don't have to close:

```
 Using connection As New MySqlConnection(connectionString)
    'More code here
 End Using ' Close the connection automatically
```

Check Complete Code Below:

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class Form16

     Dim connectionString as String = "server = localhost; user id = root;password=root; database = db"
     Dim dt as DataTable

     Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click


    Using connection As New MySqlConnection(connectionString)
      ' Use Parameterized query
      Dim commandText as String = "SELECT * FROM Voter WHERE idn=@idn"
      Dim command As New MySqlCommand(commandText, connection)
      Dim dr As MySqlDataReader

      ' Add idn value using parameterized query
      command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idn", TextBox1.Text)


      Try
        connection.Open() ' Open Connection
        dr = command.ExecuteReader()
        dt = New DataTable()
        dt.Load(dr)
        If (dt.Rows.Count > 0) Then
           Label2.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt, "fname")
           Label10.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt, "mi")
           Label11.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt, "lname")
           Label12.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt, "yr")
           Label13.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt, "sec")
           Label14.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt, "vstatus")
        Else
           MessageBox.Show("Invalid ID No.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End If

      Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
      End Try 
   End Using 

  End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: wew! thanks for the answer sir! specially for the things you have taught, i'll study all of it :D

Answer (score 0):

You have done more work than you have to...if you are going to use a datareader, your code should end up looking something like this.  (I have not tested this code)

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class Form16
    Private Sub Form16_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim con As New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;user id=root;password=root;database=db")
    Dim DataSet1 As New DataSet
    Dim dr As MySqlDataReader
    Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand

    con.ConnectionString = "server = localhost; user id = root;password=root; database = db"
    cmd.Connection = con
    con.Open()
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from voter where idn='" & TextBox1.Text & "'"
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    con.Close()


     if dr.read then

        Label2.text = dr("fname") 
        Label10.text = dr("mi")
        Label11.text = dr("lname")
        Label12.text = dr("yr") 
        Label13.text = dr("sec")
        Label14.text = dr("vstatus")

     else
        MessageBox.show("Invalid ID Number")
     endif

End Class
```